# `row.names` function used, but row names still displaying as "row1", "row2", "row3", etc

Tags: r, vegan

I'm creating a CCA diagram in R using the vegan package. My row names are showing up as row1, row2, row3, etc. in the diagram, even though I have specified `row.names = 1`. I just don't seem to be able to get rid of them!

Code:

```
env.dat <- read.table("env.data.txt", header = TRUE, row.names = 1, sep= "\t") 

mod1.cca <- cca(spec.dat ~ soil.moisture + soil.pH + light + Light.transmission, data = env.dat) plot(mod1.cca, disp=c("wa", "sp", "bp"))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `row.names(NAME_OF_DATASET) <- NULL` or replace NULL with a vector of new rownames.

Comment: thanks Stefan - tried that just - no luck!

Comment: Are you able to provide a small, reproducible example? This might help!

Comment: env.dat <- read.table("env.data.txt", header = TRUE, row.names = 1, sep= "\t")
mod1.cca <- cca(spec.dat ~ soil.moisture + soil.pH + light + Light.transmission, data = env.dat)
plot(mod1.cca, disp=c("wa", "sp", "bp"))

Comment: the issue is definitely within the env.dat dataframe, as when only plotting my species data there is not this issue!

Comment: `dput` the data and add the code to your question.

Comment: It's still not reproducible if we don't have the file you're reading. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862). By giving `row.names = 1`, you're saying the row names should come from the first column. I have no idea what you have there in your data, so it's unclear where `"row1"`, `"row2"` would come from